# React lifecycle with react hooks useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently changing my app files from `class` with lifecycle events such as `componentDidMount` to `functions` with `useEffect` hooks.

For most files I haven't seen any issues but on the below, I am getting a performance issue, where the app freezes. Zero errors or warnings in the console but my machine and Chrome increases memory used on this tab.

What have I missed?

Old Class based file code

```
listener: any;

componentDidMount() {
  const { firebase } = this.props;
  this.listener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(
    (authUser: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
      this.setState({ authUser });
    },
    () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
      this.setState({ authUser: null });
    }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.listener();
}
```

New with hooks (causing performance issues)

```
const listener = () => {
  firebase.onAuthUserListener(
    (authUser: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
      setState(authUser);
    },
    () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
      setState(null);
    }
  );
};

useEffect(() => {
  listener();
  return () => {
    listener();
  };
});
```

It may also be worth noting that I am using TypeScript with React.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't. Bad case of copy/paste from my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onAuthUserListener` returns a function to unsubscribe. This should be used when component unmounts.

In your code you are not returning the unsubscribe function.

```
const listener = () => {
  firebase.onAuthUserListener(..)    // problem here no return
}
```

So under the `useEffect` you should assign it properly and use it in `useEffect`'s return.

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(
  () => {
    //             v------ proper assignment.
    const listener = firebase.onAuthUserListener(
      (authUser: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
        setUser(authUser);
      },
      () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
        setUser(null);
      }
    );

    return () => listener();
  }
  , [] // no deps
);
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. This is what worked best for me. However, I have added `firebase` to the dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

Here might be the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
  listener();
  return () => {
    listener();  <--- here
  };
});
```

The question is, what state does need to change in order to trigger a `listener();` call?

I think this:

```
const listener = () => {
  firebase.onAuthUserListener(
    (authUser: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
      setState(authUser);
    },
    () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
      setState(null);
    }
  );
};
```

Should be transformed into a React Hook. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` needs a dependency array as second argument, otherwise it keeps running on each render. Since you are updating state, this just keeps repeating

```
useEffect(() => {
  listener();
  return () => {
    listener();
  };
}, []);
```

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

You can use tools like [Runaway Effects](https://github.com/kentcdodds/stop-runaway-react-effects) or ESLint for static analysis for figuring these out beforehand.

Comment: Thank you. That was my original thought, however I get thrown this warning `Line 37:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'listener'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: If I add `listener` to the dependancy I get `The 'listener' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 37) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'listener' definition into its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: ESLint figures that everything used inside `useEffect` is something that can change and introduce bugs, just add `listener` to the deps array, you can find more [info in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Comment: Yes, that is what I have decided upon. The reason was `listener` was being reused and pulled from another file. Adding it inside of  `useEffect` and removing the dependancy seems to have worked. Just testing now.